# How to express the following given iterated integral?

Tags: integration

Express the following iterated  integral  with the order  of integration reversed

$$\int_{-1}^{2}\int_{-x}^{2-x^2} f(x,y)dy dx$$

My attempt : The integration domain $D$ is the region sited in first quadrant between the circle $x^2+y^2=2$ and the line $y=-x$:

$$ D=\left\{(x,y)\,\,|\,\,-x<y<\sqrt{2-x^2}\,\,,\,\,-1<x<2\right\}$$ If we reverse the order, that is, variable $x$ between "functions" and variable $y$ between constants,we must split the domain in two parts $D=D_1\cup D_2$

$$ D_1=\left\{(x,y)\,\,|\,\,-y<x<\sqrt{2-y^2}\,\,,\,\,-1<y<1\right\}$$

$$ D_2=\left\{(x,y)\,\,|\,\,-1<x<\sqrt{2-y^2}\,\,,\,\,1<y<\sqrt 2\right\}$$

and then

$$\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{{-y}}^{\sqrt{2-y^2}}f(x,y)dx\,dy+\int_{1}^\sqrt2\int_{-1}^{\sqrt{2-y^2}}f(x,y)dx\,dy$$

Is  its true ?

Comment: The region of integration is between the line $y=-x$ and the inverted parabola $y=2-x^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Iterated integral of a circle section]

What you did is not quite correct. As shown in the diagram above, for region $D_2$, since $x$ is going from left side of the circle to the right side, the lower limit should be $-\sqrt{2 - y^2}$ instead. Thus, the overall integral would be

$$\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{{-y}}^{\sqrt{2-y^2}}f(x,y)dx\,dy+\int_{1}^\sqrt2\int_{-\sqrt{2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{2-y^2}}f(x,y)dx\,dy \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Comment: thanks  u @Jon Omeilan   but  integration domain $D$  is  about  first quadrant

Comment: ohhh  got it thanks  u for diagram  @john omielan

Comment: @jasmine You're welcome. I'm glad the diagram, although a bit crude, helped you. As you can see, it helps to visualize what you're doing. I used a rough hand-drawn one myself to determine your small error before I wrote the answer.